# AWS Glue Passing Parameters via Boto3 causing exception

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on here.

I am starting a Glue Job via Boto3 (from Lambda but testing locally gives the exact same issue) and when I pass parameters in via the "start job run" api I get the same error, but looking at the logs the parameters all look correct. Here is the output (I have changed some names of the buckets etc.)

Glue Code (sample):

```
def main():
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [
        'JOB_NAME',
        's3_bucket',
        's3_temp_prefix',
        's3_schema_prefix',
        's3_processed_prefix',
        'ingestion_run_id'
    ]
                              )

    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    logger = glueContext.get_logger()
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_bucket = args['s3_bucket']
    temp_prefix = args['s3_temp_prefix']
    schema_prefix = args['s3_schema_prefix']
    processed_prefix = args['s3_processed_prefix']
    ingestion_run_id = args['ingestion_run_id']

    logger.info(f's3_bucket: {s3_bucket}')
    logger.info(f'temp_prefix {temp_prefix}')
    logger.info(f'schema_prefix: {schema_prefix}')
    logger.info(f'processed_prefix: {processed_prefix}')
    logger.info(f'ingestion_run_id: {ingestion_run_id}')
```

SAM Template to make the Glue Job:

```
  CreateDataset:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      Command:
        Name: glueetl
        PythonVersion: 3
        ScriptLocation: !Sub "s3://bucket-name/GLUE/create_dataset.py"
      DefaultArguments:
        "--extra-py-files": "s3://bucket-name/GLUE/S3GetKeys.py"
        "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": ""
        "--enable-metrics": ""
      GlueVersion: 2.0
      MaxRetries: 0
      Role: !GetAtt GlueRole.Arn
      Timeout: 360
      WorkerType: Standard
      NumberOfWorkers: 15
```

Code to attempt to start the Glue Job:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='glue_admin', region_name=region)
client = session.client('glue')

name = 'CreateDataset-1uPuNfIw1Tjd'

args = {
    "--s3_bucket": 'bucket-name',
    "--s3_temp_prefix": 'TEMP',
    "--s3_schema_prefix": 'SCHEMA',
    "--s3_processed_prefix": 'PROCESSED',
    "--ingestion_run_id": 'FakeRun'
}

client.start_job_run(JobName=name, Arguments=args)
```

This starts the job fine put then the script errors and this is the log left behind, from what I can see it seems the parameters are lined up fine?

```
Wed Feb 10 09:16:00 UTC 2021/usr/bin/java -cp /opt/amazon/conf:/opt/amazon/lib/hadoop-lzo/*:/opt/amazon/lib/emrfs-lib/*:/opt/amazon/spark/jars/*:/opt/amazon/superjar/*:/opt/amazon/lib/*:/opt/amazon/Scala2.11/* com.amazonaws.services.glue.PrepareLaunch --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=29 --conf spark.executor.memory=5g --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --conf spark.driver.memory=5g --JOB_ID j_76c49a0d580594d5c0f584458cc0c9d519 --enable-metrics --extra-py-files s3://bucket-name/GLUE/S3GetKeys.py --JOB_RUN_ID jr_c0b9049abf1ee1161de189a901dd4be05694c1c42863 --s3_schema_prefix SCHEMA --enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log --s3_bucket bucket-name --scriptLocation s3://bucket-name/GLUE/create_dataset.py --s3_temp_prefix TEMP --ingestion_run_id FakeRun --s3_processed_prefix PROCESSED --JOB_NAME CreateDataset-1uPuNfIw1Tjd
```

Bucket name has been altered for this post but it matches exactly.

Fail point in Glue JOb log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "--s3_bucket"
```

The bucket name has no illegal chars but does have '-' in it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The issue is only with `--s3_bucket`? What if you remove it from the parameters and hard code its value? This can show if only this one specific parameter is a problem, or its more general issue related to the way you set these parameters.

Comment: Thanks, it makes no difference but removing   "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": ""        "--enable-metrics": "" seems to have fixed it? How strange

Comment: Glad it worked out. Don't know why cloudwatch affects it. Maybe some permission issues?

Answer (score 1):

This happened because `--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log` argument [expects a value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html) and since you didn't provide a value, the argument parser assumed the next argument is the value for it(`--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log --s3_bucket`), which in this case was `--s3_bucket`, now `--s3_bucket` is an invalid value for `--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log` option, therefore that error happens.